# How to run multiple web-sites on localhost with Apache

Tags: apache2, localhost

Please help a newbie. I've recently installed LAMP on Ubuntu 22.04.
Apache version: Apache/2.4.52

What I am trying to do is to enable multiple web-sites on my localhost. I’ve read and followed a few posts on this topic however I can’t make it work.

So this is what I’ve done so far to create two sites "prj1" and "prj2":

1. Created two folders

```
sudo mkdir /var/www/prj1
sudo mkdir /var/www/prj2
```

2. Created two index files in the folders:

```
sudo gedit /var/www/prj1/index.html
sudo gedit /var/www/prj2/index.html
```

They are simple, the first states:

```
Web prj 1. Location:


/var/www/prj1
```

The second:

```
Web prj 2. Location:


/var/www/prj2
```

3. Set permissions:

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
sudo chown -R 775 /var/www
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/prj1
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/prj2
```

4. Created .conf files for each project:
   sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/prj1.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@prj1
     ServerName prj1
     
     DocumentRoot /var/www/prj1/
     <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
     </Directory>     
     <Directory /var/www/prj1/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/prj1.webdock.io_error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/prj1.webdock.io_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

sudo gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/prj2.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerAdmin admin@prj2
     ServerName prj2
     
     DocumentRoot /var/www/prj2/
     <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
     </Directory>     
     <Directory /var/www/prj2/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/prj2.webdock.io_error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/prj2.webdock.io_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

5. Enabled sites:

```
a2ensite prj1
a2ensite prj2
```

6. Edited apache2.conf:
   sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

I’ve added the following:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/prj1"
<Directory "/var/www/prj1">
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/prj2"
<Directory "/var/www/prj2">
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
</Directory>
```

7. Added two lines in /etc/hosts:
   sudo gedit /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1 localhost prj1
127.0.0.1 localhost prj2
```

8. Restarted Apache:

```
systemctl restart apache2
```

9. 

Now I am using the following URI in the browser:

```
http://prj1.localhost/
```

this works as expected, it shows:

```
Web prj 1. Location:


/var/www/prj1
```

However if I use http://prj2.localhost/ it still shows the first site

```
Web prj 1. Location:


/var/www/prj1
```

What do I do wrong?

Thank you,
Alex

Comment: In your step 3, "`sudo chown -R 775 /var/www`" doesn't make sense. Also, this seems to be about Apache, not Ubuntu.

Comment: yeah, at first I didn't use the line, then I found it in one of the posts and tried. The whole thing didn't work in either case...

Answer (score 1):

I've found what the problem was. In the prj2.conf the port for prj2 was 81 not 80. Honestly I don't know how that happened, I can't even say it was a typo since the whole text was copy/pasted.
Anyways, after I changed it to 80 both sites are now working.

In the file /etc/host the lines should be

> 127.0.0.1 prj1

> 127.0.0.1 prj2

The URLs are to be [http://prj1](https://prj1) and [http://prj2](https://prj2). The only thing is that the browser tells that connection to the sites "Not secure" (I don't know why).

I thank all the contributors to the post.

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Good that you solved it. The browser says "not secure" because the connection is over plain HTTP and not HTTPS. That's what modern browsers do if they encounter a plain HTTP connection. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thank you for this clarification Raj!

Answer (score 0):

Step 7 should be:

```
127.0.0.1 prj1.localhost
127.0.0.1 prj2.localhost
```

Comment: Hi Parto, thank you for your suggestion. Just tried, no luck...

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, `/etc/hosts` file needs to have **one line per IP address**. So you should put **all** hostnames that refer to `127.0.0.1` in one line, like:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost prj1 prj2
```

Also I'm not sure why you are using plain hostnames `prj1` and `prj2` both in your `hosts` file and in `ServerName` directives in Apache config, but are using `prj1.localhost` and `prj2.localhost` in the URLs. I would rather try just `http://prj1/` and `http://prj2/`.

Comment: Hi Raj, thank you for stepping in. I tried putting it into one line - still no result. As to URLs, honestly, I don't know what URL is correct, I tried a few combinations including the one you suggested. The only difference when using prj2 instead of prj2.localhost is that the browser warns that the connection is not secure

Comment: It would be nice to know what request is exactly sent by your browser. Maybe it messes something up. Can you get it using Developer tools window in your browser?
You can also try to manually connect via telnet to port 80 and simulate the HTTP request, sending hostname `prj1` or `prj2` - if you get the correct site then server part is working properly, and the issue is definitely on the client (browser) side - in that case it may be impossible to make it work properly

Comment: you can ignore the documentation. we use the same ip adress with different alias for years now in our company, we won't change our automated scripts after 5+ years of this working without problems. check out whether there are the automatically generated ipv6 entries. trying it at home (these are not present at my work) it failed whenever i put the ipv4 entries behind them. when placing it before, it worked